# How to upload image to Azure Blob Storage with proper content type

Tags: node.js, file-upload, azure-blob-storage

I've read most of the documentation provided by MS to upload files/image to Blob Storage. It's been two days now and I'm stuck. I don't find an appropriate way to upload image with proper content-type. The file/image is uploaded but the content-type after upload to BLOB Storage is changed to 'application/octet-stream'. I want it to be 'image/png' or 'image/jpg' etc. for an image.

There are [samples](https://medium.com/@theodor.chichirita/upload-images-in-azure-blob-storage-1495889068af) of [C#](https://medium.com/@theodor.chichirita/upload-images-in-azure-blob-storage-1495889068af) code but they are not useful. 
I'm trying with node.js

SDK Library Used : [*@azure/storage-blob*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-blob)

References :

- https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/javascript/azure-storage-blob/12.0.1/classes/blockblobclient.html#uploadfile
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest

[image: Content of the BLOB Container.]

Sample Code :

```
const bc = new BlockBlobClient(
    rhcConfig.STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING,
    rhcConfig.CONTAINER_NAME,
    `IMAGES/${fileName}`
  );

  // let result = await bc.uploadFile(_file);
  // console.log(result);

  const buff = Buffer.from(file, "base64");
  const stream = getStream(buff);
  const streamLength = buff.length;
  await bc.uploadStream(stream, streamLength, 1, { httpHeaderOptions });
```

**httpHeaderOptions :**

```
const httpHeaders = {
    "x-ms-blob-cache-control": "1000",
    "x-ms-blob-content-type": "image/png",
    "x-ms-blob-content-md5": `${md5Hash}`,
    "x-ms-blob-content-encoding": "compress",
    "x-ms-blob-content-language": "en",
    "x-ms-blob-content-disposition": "multipart/form-data",
  };
  const httpHeaderOptions = { blobHTTPHeaders: httpHeaders };
```

Thanks to the community !!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose your `httpHeaderOptions` format is not correct, you could refer to this interface description:[BlobHTTPHeaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blobhttpheaders?view=azure-node-latest), below is my test code.

```
const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionstr)

const containerClient=blobServiceClient.getContainerClient('test')
const blobclient=containerClient.getBlockBlobClient('test.jpg')
let fileStream = fs.createReadStream('E:\\dog.jpg');
const blobOptions = { blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: 'image/jpg' } };
blobclient.uploadStream(fileStream,undefined ,undefined ,blobOptions)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! I did this today and was about to share it. I don't find the MS documentation easier to implement. This is exactly what I did and it is working.

Comment: @Debadatta Meher, if this could work, you could accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and like the original poster found the micosoft documnetation and examples rather shockingly bad. I would have thought uploading images is a rather common thing to do but none of their examples show up to change the content type using the newer storage api.  Anyhow, my implementation was simliar to  George Chen's and is as follows`

BlobClient blobClient = photoContainer.GetBlobClient(fileName);
blobClient.UploadAsync(f.InputStream, new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = "image/jpeg" }).`